# CakePHP and COUNT on very deep association

Tags: cakephp

let say, I have the following tables: Cities which hasMany Streets which hasMany Houses which hasMany Flats which hasMany People.

Now I am in /cities/index view and would like to display number of People in every City.

What I do now is findAll on Cities with big "recursion" set and dumb foreach() on the result.

Is there a better way?

Thank you very much for your time and patience.

-Jan Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DO NOT DO THAT!**

Apologies for the capitols but that is a bad bad idea. Mostly because as the data on your DB increases, those are going to be some really heavy calls. If you have a look at the SQL log, you'll notice that having a recursion above 0 will run several queries for each of your entities.

I speak with experience here. When I started out with cake, my apps started to get a white screen of death! Upon inspection, it turned out I was running out of memory.

I'd recommend you either do a `->query()` call (using native SQL) or run several smaller queries, each time getting the ID of the entity and going deeper.

Also, just curious. Why does Houses have many Flats? I would have thought Houses and Flats would be on the same level?

Welcome to SO!

Comment: It's maybe just a bad translation, maybe you don't know what kind of houses we have in Czech Republic (former Soviet block) :) [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panelak). Anyway it was just an example. My real table structure is much more complicated. Nevertheless thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh I see! Yeah, probably just lost in translation. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your question. See here for why it's helpful : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234